# Perl: Can I access two different levels of an array of hashes at the same time by using indices?

Tags: perl

I'm completely new to Perl and I need to write a program that clusters found matches if they are at a certain distance from each other. So I got an array of hashes containing on each level the begin position, the end position and the number of matches present in a cluster(1 in the beginning).

If I want to know if the distance between two matches is ok, I  do Begin2-End1

```
my $DEBUG = 1;
my @hitsarray =();
my ($beginarray,$endarray,$aantalarray);
my $hit = { BEGIN => $beginarray,   EIND => $endarray,   MATCHES => $aantalarray, };
for (my $k = 0;$k <= $#beginarray;$k++)
{    
    print $beginarray[$k],"\t",$endarray[$k],"\t",$aantalarray[$k],"\n" if ($DEBUG);
    $hit = ();
    $hit->{BEGIN} = $beginarray[$k];
    $hit->{END} = $endarray[$k];
    $hit->{MATCHES} = $aantalarray[$k];
    push (@hitsarray,$hit);
}
for ( my $m = 0; $m <= $#hitsarray; $m++)
{        
    while($hitsarray[$m+1]{BEGIN} - $hitsarray[$m]{END} < 5 && $hitsarray[$m+1]{BEGIN} - $hitsarray[$m]{END} > 3)
    {
        $hitsarray[$m]{END} = $hitsarray[$m+1]{EIND};
        $hitsarray[$m]{MATCHES} +=1;
        delete $hitsarray[$m+1];
        print $beginarray[$m],"\t",$endarray[$m],"\t",$aantalarray[$m],"\n" if ($DEBUG);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work! My pc gets in a loop and states "Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at script line 55."

It probably has to do something with using references but I don't really understand those..
I also tried a simpler structure with two non-connected arrays but I've got the same problem;

*How do you use elements from different lines*  (and from different arrays)  *for subtraction?*

Any help is totally welcome!!

Comment: I only see about 20 lines here. Which line is line 55?

Comment: You seem to have both EIND and END used as subscripts - is that really what you intended?  (Good programmers have to be consistent spellers, even if they don't spell correctly.)

Answer (score 6):

I know that this might not seem to be the most helpful, but your code is so wrong that there is not a single problem or a single correction.  Here are some of the problems.

1. put `use warnings; use strict;` at the top of your script.
2. $beginarray, $endarray and $aantalarray are all scalars, not arrays.  You might want them to be references to arrays, but they aren't because you never assign them.  NOTE:  when you do `$beginarray[$m]` that is referencing an array variable called @beginarray which is the same name but actually a different variable from $beginarray which is a scalar.
3. You aren't showing us everything if you are having a problem on line 55
4. this, `$hit = ();` actually just sets the **SCALAR** variable $hit to 0 because that is the length of the array `()`.
5. $#beginarray is going to be -1 because @beginarray is not declared.  Even if you changed your code to declare it, it still has no data so the first look won't run.
6. `delete $hitsarray[$m+1]` will remove that value from the array, but that index will just be empty, the items above it will not move in the array.  To remove an item from an array you need either to grep into a new array or splice the existing array.

You need to make a much smaller example or working with arrays to figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Also place "use warnings;" at the top of your script before the "use strict;" line

Comment: @David: Does the relative placement of `use warnings;` and `use strict;` make any difference?  I usually place strict before warnings (as it happens), but I really don't think the order matters -- does it?

Comment: I don't think it matters.  I always put strict before warnings myself.

Comment: It matters if you barewordly do: `use strict vars;` which I've seen people do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( my $m = 0; $m <= $#hitsarray; $m++)
{        
    while($hitsarray[$m+1]{BEGIN} - $hitsarray[$m]{END} < 5 && $hitsarray[$m+1]{BEGIN} - $hitsarray[$m]{END} > 3)
```

Here you are using element $m+1, which is beyond the end of the array on the final for iteration.  Perhaps your for loop should say `$m < $#hitsarray`.